# Azure Service Fabric WebAPI with SignalR

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, signalr, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric cluster with a web API with signalR and a reliable actor setup.

I also have a separate MVC application that hits the web API.

I can connect to the signalR just fine with MVC app just fine and everything works well.  But when I hit the API with the reliable actor which should then trigger a signalR broadcast to the group the MVC app is connected to, nothing comes across on my MVC app.  I know it is hitting the API as I have it logging to be sure.

I have set the load balancer to Session persistence  to Client IP.  I am suspecting that the signalR hub might not be the same 'hub' or its on another node?  Is there any way I can force it to all be on the same one so this communicates?  Am I forgetting anything?  Please let me know if I need to include more information.

Comment: Can it be that some traffic goes to one SignalR server but the clients are connected to the other and they don't see messages because you don't have any backplane so the servers are not talking to each other?

Answer (score 2):

The answer I found was [SignalR Scaleout with Redis](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis)

Basically this uses redis to share signalR messages across all nodes in the service fabric.

Simply set up Redis, reference `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis` and add this to your startup:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(redisConnectionString, "SignalR"));
```